# github.com/jquery/jquery as git submodule

Tags: jquery, git, git-submodules

I'd like to use a local copy of jQuery 1.8.3 for my github project. I'd like to do it the right way, which would be to add it as a submodule:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git js/lib/jquery
```

Done! The problem is the jQuery repository does not have prebuilt versions of jQuery, and other javascript libraries that I'm using do. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build it yourself locally. There are some [instructions](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery) on the GitHub project page.

Comment: Is there really a point in it being a submodule, then? Why not just download it and add a rule in `.gitignore`?

Comment: It'd be exactly the same as using the pre-build version from the repository which you were going to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the right way does not mean adding a submodule.

You could perfectly use a lightweight .js file or simply use a CDN that will be better for your server.

Comment: Pointing to a CDN doesn't support developing offline, unlike checked in .js or submodule.